# Trying to print "tie" for rock paper scissors game but the game always gives the win to the computer

Tags: python

In my Python class we are making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game but every time the game is supposed to tie, it gives the computer the win. Its obviously supposed to print a tie but prints computer wins! instead. How do I fix it? Here is my code:

```
#computer choice code.  Copy and paste the code from the instructions.
import random
computerChoice = random.randint(1,3)

#player choice code
playerChoice = int(input("Please choose a number between 1 and 3: "))

#who won?
if (playerChoice == computerChoice):
    result = """
  _______ _      _ 
 |__   __(_)    | |
    | |   _  ___| |
    | |  | |/ _ \ |
    | |  | |  __/_|
    |_|  |_|\___(_)
                   
                   """
if (playerChoice == 1 and computerChoice == 3 or \
    playerChoice == 2 and computerChoice == 1 or \
    playerChoice == 3 and computerChoice == 2):
        result = """
 __     __          __          ___       _ 
 \ \   / /          \ \        / (_)     | |
  \ \_/ /__  _   _   \ \  /\  / / _ _ __ | |
   \   / _ \| | | |   \ \/  \/ / | | '_ \| |
    | | (_) | |_| |    \  /\  /  | | | | |_|
    |_|\___/ \__,_|     \/  \/   |_|_| |_(_)
                                            
                                            """
else:
    result = """
   _____ _____  _    _  __          ___           _ 
  / ____|  __ \| |  | | \ \        / (_)         | |
 | |    | |__) | |  | |  \ \  /\  / / _ _ __  ___| |
 | |    |  ___/| |  | |   \ \/  \/ / | | '_ \/ __| |
 | |____| |    | |__| |    \  /\  /  | | | | \__ \_|
  \_____|_|     \____/      \/  \/   |_|_| |_|___(_)
                                                    
                                                    """
    
print(result)
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Comment: The `if` that's checking for "You Win!" should be an `elif` instead.  Currently, the `else` that produces "CPU Wins!" applies in every case where "You Win!" doesn't - including ties.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Follow the execution of your program when `playerChoice == computerChoice`. What happens to `result`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is your second "if" (or the "else" part) always executes, consequently the "result" gets always overwritten with "You win" or "CPU wins".

To fix it, just change it to elif

```
if (playerChoice == computerChoice):
    result = """
  _______ _      _ 
 |__   __(_)    | |
    | |   _  ___| |
    | |  | |/ _ \ |
    | |  | |  __/_|
    |_|  |_|\___(_)
                   
                   """
elif (playerChoice == 1 and computerChoice == 3 or \
    playerChoice == 2 and computerChoice == 1 or \
    playerChoice == 3 and computerChoice == 2):
        result = """
 __     __          __          ___       _ 
 \ \   / /          \ \        / (_)     | |
  \ \_/ /__  _   _   \ \  /\  / / _ _ __ | |
   \   / _ \| | | |   \ \/  \/ / | | '_ \| |
    | | (_) | |_| |    \  /\  /  | | | | |_|
    |_|\___/ \__,_|     \/  \/   |_|_| |_(_)
                                            
                                            """
else:
    result = """
   _____ _____  _    _  __          ___           _ 
  / ____|  __ \| |  | | \ \        / (_)         | |
 | |    | |__) | |  | |  \ \  /\  / / _ _ __  ___| |
 | |    |  ___/| |  | |   \ \/  \/ / | | '_ \/ __| |
 | |____| |    | |__| |    \  /\  /  | | | | \__ \_|
  \_____|_|     \____/      \/  \/   |_|_| |_|___(_)
                                                    
                                                    """
    
print(result)
```

Comment: Im slamming my head against my desk right now in rage. Thank you.